# Can I change actions upon inactivity and timeout for that from command line?

Tags: command-line, power-management, suspend

How do I set the policy about what action should be taken if the computer is inactive for some time. This can be easily done from GUI, via Power Manager.

I am trying to do this from command line. I need to essentially set the action to "Suspend", and "when inactive for" time to 10 minutes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

That's a `dconf` value. It can be easly set via `gsettings`. Type this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 600
```

`600` is the value in seconds. If you set it to `0` it is the equivalent to `never suspend`.